# При получение даних с json в listView отображаеться только первая запись Android

Tags: android, listview, retrofit2

Получаю дание с сервера и заношу их в List. В логах отображаються все записи, а в list view только первая.
Адаптер

```
    package com.pllug.course.ivankiv.retrofitlesson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by iw97d on 28.01.2018.
 */

public class TagAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private final Context context;
        private final List<Tag> tagList;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public TagAdapter(Context context, List<Tag> tagList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.tagList = tagList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tagList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Tag getItem(int position) {
            return tagList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Tag tag = tagList.get(position);
            mViewHolder.textViewName.setText(tag.getName());
            mViewHolder.textViewCount.setText(Integer.toString(tag.getCount()));

            return convertView;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {
            TextView textViewName;
            TextView textViewCount;

            public MyViewHolder(View item) {
                textViewName = item.findViewById(R.id.name);
                textViewCount = item.findViewById(R.id.count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Код MainActivity

```
    package com.pllug.course.ivankiv.retrofitlesson;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "myLog";


    private List<Tag> tags;


    private ListView listView;
    private TagAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        initData();
        initAdapter();

    }



    private void initView() {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    }

    private void initData() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.stackexchange.com")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        StackOverflowAPI stackOverflowAPI = retrofit.create(StackOverflowAPI.class);

        Call<StackOverflowTags> call = stackOverflowAPI.loadPopularTags();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<StackOverflowTags>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StackOverflowTags> call, Response<StackOverflowTags> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Успішно!");
                    tags = new ArrayList<>();

                    tags = response.body().getItems();
                    Log.d(TAG, "size: " + tags.size());
                    adapter = new TagAdapter(MainActivity.this, tags);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    for (Tag tag : tags) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "name: " + tag.getName() + " count - " + tag.getCount());
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Помилка!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StackOverflowTags> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void initAdapter() {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Как вивести все записи в ListView?

Comment: Разметку покажи. Может у тебя просто виден только первый элемент? Не пробовал пролистывать?